# Regex: Find specific string as long as it occurs before another specific string

Tags: javascript, regex

Yep, another regex (javascript implementation) question...

I can't figure out how to find the string 'cat' as long as it occurs anywhere ahead of 'dog'.

So for the following sentence...

```
cat categorically hates the dog, im going to mention cat again.
```

The first and second occurrences will be found, not the last one.

Comment: Judging from your example (and the accepted answer) you probably want "substrings", not "words".

Comment: The accepted answer is incorrect as it does not find the instances of cat which are ahead of dog. My answer below finds the instances of cat which are ahead of dog.

Comment: @Fresh - as I mentioned below, you need to explain this. "Ahead of" and "before" mean the same thing, unless there's a usage I haven't heard of.

Comment: @jwismar A synonym of "ahead" is "in front" (google for "define ahead"), so this could be re-worded "'cat' as long as it occurs anywhere in front of 'dog'". Hence the reason why I expected to see a regex which finds the last instance of cat i.e. the one in front of dog.

Comment: "In front," "before," or "ahead of," in this context all mean "toward the beginning."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a lookahead:

```
/cat(?=.*dog)/
```

matches any "cat" that is followed anywhere by a "dog", taking into account that there may be other characters in between.

Comment: @Z-Mehn This is incorrect as your question asked for instances of cat which occur ahead of dog. This regex finds instances of cat which occur before dog. Also the second instance of car found by this in not a word, its a substring of "categorically".

Comment: @Fresh - you need to explain why "ahead of" is different from "before". You're using the words in a way that I don't understand.

Comment: See my comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions states:

> I can't figure out how to find the word 'cat' as long as it occurs
>   anywhere ***ahead of 'dog'***.

The regular expression for this is:

```
cat(?!.*dog)
```

This uses negative lookup to find cat which is not followed by dog.

Comment: @thg435 because this regex finds instances of cat which are not followed by dog. Hence when applied to the string in the question it will find the last instance of cat (i.e. the instance of cat ahead of dog)

Comment: He asked for instances of "cat" that appear *ahead of* dog, which means *before* dog. Your regex does the opposite.

Comment: Yes, I think we experince a kind of cognitive dissonance here. We use a look_ahead_ to find out what's _behind_ the string. +1 for making me think of it. ;)

Comment: @jwismar See my comment on the question

Comment: @thg435 Ah ha, I understand Fresh's confusion now. Now that you mention it, "lookahead" in the regex sense is a bit confusing, isn't it? Fortunately, Z-Mehn described what he was looking for right there in his question, ("The first and second occurrences will be found, not the last one.") which is the everyday use of "ahead of", not the regex lookahead sense.

Comment: @jwismar lol, I can see where you are coming from. As I've said before, I took the sentence "'cat' as long as it occurs anywhere ahead of 'dog'" literally, hence why I still believe ahead means in front (ahead is always ahead in my head!) >_<. Anyway, whoever else reads this post will get a good education in lookahead and negative look-up regular expressions!