# regex - find the string before the last occurence

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string which is generated like this

```
"$PmyCase$l2$pClaimData$pTriageDetails$pDamagedAreas$l3$ppySelected"
```

I want to make use of a javascript regex to find out the string before the last occurence of "[letter l][digit]". So my result should be

```
$PmyCase$l2$pClaimData$pTriageDetails$pDamagedAreas
```

since I am very new to regular expression, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex: Find specific string as long as it occurs before another specific string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171026/regex-find-specific-string-as-long-as-it-occurs-before-another-specific-string)

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookahead to match all the characters before the last occurance of `$l` followed by a digit.

```
> "$PmyCase$l2$pClaimData$pTriageDetails$pDamagedAreas$l3$ppySelected".match(/.+(?=\$l\d)/g);
[ '$PmyCase$l2$pClaimData$pTriageDetails$pDamagedAreas' ]
```

Or Place a dot instead of `\$` if it contain any character before `l<digit>`,

```
> "$PmyCase$l2$pClaimData$pTriageDetails$pDamagedAreas$l3$ppySelected".match(/.+(?=.l\d)/g);
[ '$PmyCase$l2$pClaimData$pTriageDetails$pDamagedAreas' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
var input = "$PmyCase$l2$pClaimData$pTriageDetails$pDamagedAreas$l3$ppySelected";
var output = input.match(/^(.*)\$l\d/)[1];
```

If no matches found - `output` will be `undefined`.